# Use O/S Env Var for OpenShift Deployment Environment Configuration

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I would like to provide an environment variable to an OpenShift pod and within that variable reference other environment variables defined in the container.

For example, I define an environment variable called JAVA_CMD_LINE in OpenShift and set it to:

```
$HEAP_SETTING -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/.keystore/cacerts -jar abc.jar
```

Where $HEAP_SETTING is set to -XMX=1G when the container starts.

In my container, there is a startup script that looks like:

```
java $JAVA_CMD_LINE
```

What I would expect is that then the container runs, the following is executed:

```
java -XMX=1G -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/.keystore/cacerts -jar abc.jar
```

But instead what I see is:

```
java '$HEAP_SETTING' -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/.keystore/cacerts -jar abc.jar
```

How do I provide the variable?

**Update**: Adding details from the YML file.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH
          value: 'true'
        - name: OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_REDIRECT_PROMPT
          value: 'true'
        - name: KUBERNETES_MASTER
          value: 'https://kubernetes.default:443'
        - name: KUBERNETES_TRUST_CERTIFICATES
          value: 'true'
        - name: JAVA_CMD_LINE
          value: >-
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/cert/.keystore/cacerts
            -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
            $HEAP_SETTING
```

**Update 2** - The error that I see:

```
+ exec java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/jenk-cert/.keystore/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 '$(HEAP_SETTING)' -Duser.home=/var/lib/jenkins -Djavamelody.application-name=JENKINS -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
Error: Could not find or load main class $(HEAP_SETTING)
```

Comment: Can you share the manifest? Without seeing it it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Is this your own Java image, or are you using one of the OpenShift S2I images?

Comment: It is my own image. Based on OpenShift Jenkins image

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas, manifest details added.

Comment: Is the Git repository you are using to build your custom image available on a public repository so we can see it? Or when you say is based on OpenShift Jenkins image, does that mean you copied its repo and modified it, or you use ``FROM`` in a derived docker build to create it? Where is ``HEAP_SETTING`` actually being set?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the git repo is an internally hosted one. I am using FROM to build my image based on openshift/jenkins. HEAP_SETTING is being set by the start up script for the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH
          value: 'true'
        - name: OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_REDIRECT_PROMPT
          value: 'true'
        - name: KUBERNETES_MASTER
          value: 'https://kubernetes.default:443'
        - name: KUBERNETES_TRUST_CERTIFICATES
          value: 'true'
        - name: JAVA_CMD_LINE
          value: >-
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/cert/.keystore/cacerts
            -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
            $(HEAP_SETTING)
```

Any time you are setting the value of an environment variable, if you need to compose the value from other environment variables that are already being set, you can use `$(<VARNAME>)` in the value.

IOW, use `$(HEAP_SETTING)` and not just `$HEAP_SETTING`.

---

UPDATE 1

Actually this will not work. This is because `HEAP_SETTING` is not in the set of environment variables you are setting via the deployment config, so it will pass the literal value `$(HEAP_SETTING)`. This can't be used where the environment variable you are trying to use is populated by startup code in the image.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that what I am trying is not possible?

Comment: Without any visibility of what your additions are doing and not knowing for sure what base image you are using, impossible to give any advice. Neither the ``HEAP_SETTING`` or ``JAVA_CMD_LINE`` variable are present in the source code for the repo for the OpenShift jenkins image repo at https://github.com/openshift/jenkins If they are from your changes, then you should have control to change things, but can only guess since don't know what you currently have.

Comment: FWIW, the fact that ``JAVA_CMD_LINE`` wipes out the existing command line arguments looks to be just wrong. Usually you would implement things so environment variables were additive to the command line and not wipe out parts of it defined in a base image. If that was done this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Graham, the example above is a simplified version of what I am actually doing. In actuality I am adding a path to a cert file to the Java command line. The image uses JENKINS_JAVA_OPTS to specify JVM arguments and I have no trouble overwriting that to have my cert path but in doing so I lose the other values. The crux of the question is if OpenShift can set an environment variable that can reference other variables defined within the container.

Comment: Why can't you just change ``java $JAVA_CMD_LINE`` to ``java $HEAP_SETTING $JAVA_CMD_LINE`` in your script?

Comment: I can. I would just have to modify the image and use a customized script. I just wanted to know if there were other options.

Comment: You can't use ``HEAP_SETTING`` before it is set. In normal usage, there is no concept of lazy evaluation such that the value will be magically injected at a later point if wasn't set originally. It will be replaced with empty value at first use. So I can't really see any other way you to could easily do it.

Comment: Males sense, that's what I was missing. At the time that my container is made, the environment variables set by OpenShift are created before the ones made by the script, and therefore they cannot reference the script variables. .